# Copy partial rows from one table to another with the corresponding rows from a different table

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables, one with Transactions and one with TransactionsItems.
TransactionsItem has a foreign key to a Transaction.

The Transaction has a Datetime. I only want to transfer the Transactions that has a date that is larger than x.

How can I create a query that copies all Transactions with a date larger than x and the TransactionsItems that is connected to those Transactions to two other tables?

I know how to select the Transactions with a date larger than x, I also know how to copy those transaction from one table to another if it was only that table, what I don't know is how to copy the TransactionItems that is connected to the copied Transaction also.

Thanks
Anders

Comment: Join the tables and use a `WHERE yourDateColumn > 'somedate'`

Comment: If I join the tables won't it transfer the columns from TransactionItem to the same table? Can you make a complete script?